# Apply colsum and rowsum to every element in matrix with single function

Tags: r, matrix

This might be a newbie question but here goes:

I'm really new to R and I'm trying to make a function which will do pretty much this (example for a `2 × 2` matrix):

```
studiekeuze=table(read.table(file.choose(),h=T));
matrix(c(rowSums(studiekeuze)*matrix(colSums(studiekeuze))[1],
rowSums(studiekeuze)*matrix(colSums(studiekeuze))[2]),nrow=2)/sum(studiekeuze)
```

Is there a single function for this in R?

If not, how can I write my own function? Preferrably something that will also allow for matrices of `n × n` size.

Comment: you know we don't have your data, right? and your question is confusing. You want to sum the entire row for each single element of a matrix? and repeat for the column sums?

Comment: Sorry for not supplying the data, I thought what I wanted was obvious. Each element has a row and a column. I want each to apply (colsum) and (rowsum) to each element of the matrix. *example: the element on the 3rd row and the 2nd column, should have the `rowsum(3rd row)*colsum(2nd column)` as value, for all values in my matrix*

Comment: `outer(rowSums(mat), colSums(mat), "*")` maybe?

Comment: @Euryris what you want is not obvious at all. It's easy to make example data, e.g. `m <- matrix( 1:4 , 2 , 2 )`. Use that and show the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next please provide a reproducible example with expected output but I am assuming you want this where m is the input matrix:

```
outer(rowSums(m), colSums(m)) / sum(m)
```